# MySQL SUM of the total COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, sum

```
Seat Type   Quantity left


Business        23
Economy         27
First           15

            Total quantity left : ?
```

DBMS = MySQL

I've tried the following SQL which to print the above information

```
$sql = "SELECT SeatType, COUNT(SeatType)AS quantity
              FROM  seat

              WHERE SeatAvailable = 'Yes'  
              GROUP BY SeatType
              ";
```

How can i sum up the total quantity left(eg:23+27+25) ?
Thx for the help in advanced...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(SeatType, 'Total quantity left') `Seat Type`, 
        COUNT(SeatType)AS quantity
FROM    seat
WHERE   SeatAvailable = 'Yes'  
GROUP   BY SeatType WITH ROLLUP
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c8052/1)
- [GROUP BY Modifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: the total quantity left i need to sum it with AS a new name .......because i print the variable name later in html

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
select sum(quantity_left) SeatsRemaining
from etc
```